# Send a Click via Javascript console (chrome broswer console)

Tags: google-chrome, javascript, console

The whole webpage is like a javascipt container/iframe (i dont know the term) where there isn't really any element to click on. I basically want this click to keep alive the webpage. is there any way to send a random mouse event or random (or even specific) keyboard activity through the browser's javascipt console?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

A webpage always has some element (assuming its a proper web page with `html` and `body` tags). So you can use java script click commands, try to approach body or any other tag under body tag via DOM and perform `click();` function as it is possible to click on any `HtmlElement`, you can check the source code of that page to know what elements (tags) are available to you
general command is:

```
document.getElementByTagName("p")[0].click();
```

This will click first paragraph element assuming it is there in the page

In case of iframe, you can either open that iframe directly and then use click method or approach the iframe as explained here: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_element_iframe.asp

Comment: there isn't any elements, really. the site is similler to https://vscode.dev/.

Comment: I tried this and it returned 1 so body tag is certainly there, a web page only knows HTML, 
`document.getElementsByTagName("body").length;`
yes the page link u sent is a tuff one to hack around for click:

Comment: after trying it I was able to click one of links, try this code on the link you sent:
`for(var i=12;i<13;i++)
document.getElementsByTagName("a")[i].click();`

and I can get to other elements as well, for instance this tells me there are 4 paragraphs:
`document.getElementsByTagName("p").length;`

Comment: i did as you said but it retures undefined.

Comment: Thats fine, you can test to click on any element on any webpage, it will mostly show undefined, I dont know exact technical reason for that, but even I tested it on a simple div element on this very page where I am commenting and it still shows undefined, but it means the click was done.

Comment: you can try clicking on different elements and for most of them it will show undefined. Probably its the default message or return value from a `click();` function

Comment: Also, as per your OP, you probably need to avoid the sleep or session timeout scenarios, I can suggest you to use some mouse tools that click automatically after your pre-defined interval, just google it and test 2/3 of such apps

Comment: My best guess is, if the click function is not defined for an element, it will return undefined. And for any typical buttons/links there is usually something that is either written by developer or a default behavior of click like in buttons and links